# How to Inject Singleton EJB(Container Resource) into POJO(non Container resource)?

Tags: jboss7.x, cdi, ejb-3.1

I want to inject a Singleton EJB into my POJO class.
With the new EJB 3.1 spec, is it possible to inject an EJB into a POJO?
I know in EJB 3.0, the @EJB annotation could be used to inject an EJB, but this did not work on simple POJOs.
`@javax.inject.Inject` is also not working for me.

One more thing is, what is the difference between a container and a non-container resource?
How do I achieve it, I am using JBoss AS 7.1.1.

Comment: Your last question is incomplete: what is the difference between what?

Comment: to use @Inject you should have the beans.xml file. Please refer to this: http://www.seamframework.org/Documentation/WhatIsBeansxmlAndWhyDoINeedIt

Comment: Thanks bkail and Chechus , Sorry I missed out last question...
My Question was,  what is the difference between container resource and non container resource ?  if possible plz suggest any example...

Comment: I don't think "container resource" is a spec-defined term; where did find it? Anyway, it presumably means "an object created/injected by the container" as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

EE is designed around the idea of component classes (EJBs, servlets, etc.).  An EE container can only perform injection when it controls the creation of the object, which does not apply for POJO, so you cannot use EE injection on POJO objects.

For CDI to work, you need to add `META-INF/beans.xml` to your archive.  Even then, you cannot create the POJO instance using `new`.  You always have to let the container create the instance, so either `@Inject` the POJO, which can then `@Inject` the EJB, or use `javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager`.

Comment: Thanks bkail and Chechus , Sorry I missed out last question... My Question was,
1) what is the difference between container resource and non container resource ? if possible plz suggest any example... –
2) what is the use of Producer Methods in CDI?

Answer (score 3):

`@EJB` won't work for you so you have only two options - JNDI lookup or using `CDI`. Something like

```
@Inject
private MyEJB ejb;
```

should work for you. Also check that you have `beans.xml` in the `WEB-INF` folder in order to activate `CDI` container.

And for the difference - it is almost the same (while it's recommended to use `@Inject`) with only exception - you still have to use `@EJB` for injecting remote beans.

Reason why you can't use `service = new ServiceClass();` is that `service` object will not be managed by the container - that means that no injections will be peformed after creation of this class because container is no longer in control of this object. Very naively said, if you do

```
@Inject
ServiceClass service;
```

container will create new instance, then perform injections and return it to you.

Comment: Thanks Petr , 
I already tried according to your approach , It is working fine if some servlet try to inject EJB.
But whenever I create object of POJO class inside servlet "doget" method & inside POJO class I try to inject EJB  , its returning null.

Comment: I am attaching code snippet as well:
Servlet doGET method :--->
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
 ServiceClass service  = new ServiceClass();
 service.contactEJB();
}

ServiceClass as follows:

@Inject
private ITestSingletonEJB testSingletonEJB ;

public void contactEJB()
{
 testSingletonEJB.doProcessing();
}

Comment: Plz let me knw If i made any mistake,Eagrly waiting for ur reply :)

Comment: Ok, I guess this is caused by calling `service = new ServiceClass();`. You don't need to create this object (you want container to call `new`, create this object and perform all the injections (the `EJB` bean in your case). So just use the snippet from answer and don't create POJOs or any other beans by yourself, just let the container to do this.

Comment: Thnks Petr , but I am still not very clear why we cant inject ejb from POJO like service = new ServiceClass() ?
 1)what is the difference between container resource and non container resource ? if possible plz suggest any example...
2) what is the use of Producer Methods in CDI?